# How to Open Powerpoint file in Browser using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I want to open Powerpoint file directly in browser(Google chrome). I am using this code, but this code only saves the file directly. I want to open that Chrome file in browser where all slides can be view..

here is my code

```
string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Attachments/Sample.ppt");
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);
            if (file.Exists)
            {
                Response.ClearContent();               
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + file.Name);                
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint";               
                file.IsReadOnly = true;
                Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);              
                Response.End();
            }
```

but this code is saving file directly but not showing the slides of PowerPoint file directly in browser(Google Chrome)

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

The `Response.TransmitFile` is meant to send a file as a download to the user.
It is doing what you asked it to do.

If you want to embed the presentation onto your website you will have to look for other alternatives. Office these days has a few options using PowerPoint webaccess

Take a look at: [Embed a Presentation on Your Site](http://www.microsoft.com/web/solutions/powerpoint-embed.aspx)
This relies on office online, but there are many other ways to embed your presentation on a website. [SlideShare](http://www.slideshare.net/) is another popular atlernative.